Why does Chromium (Edge) send two HTTP requests for an audio resource?
My scenario:
I have a URL for an MP3 stream, which I paste Edge's address bar and press Enter. I see two GET requests in the developer tools:

The first one is of type document and receives only 16.2 kB;
The second one is of type media and receives the full stream.


I also see two requests in nginx' access logs. In my server logs, I also see an exception:

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

...which usually means the client closed the connection.

I tried the same with Firefox and VLC and they made only one HTTP request.
My MP3 stream starts with frames without ID3 metadata, while it may contain ID3 metadata at the end.
The audio is real-time generated. Since I don't know how long the body will be, I cannot set the content length in the HTTP header.
I'm using ResponseBodyEmitter in my Java server. I got ClientAbortException in my first call to output.flush().

My questions are:

Why does Edge (or Chromium) close the connection and creates a new one?
How to prevent this behavior?


Are those 2 HTTP GET requests or is the first one a HTTP HEAD and the second one a HTTP GET?

@AmigoJack Both are GET. Question updated.
